# Http PUT to do incremental updates

Tags: http, rest, post, restlet, put

We've implemented a RESTful webservice. Here's how it looks like

```
GET /person/1234
GET /person/list

POST /person
POST /person/list

PUT /person/1234
PUT /person/list
```

Basically, to create a Person, you POST to /person or /person/list

To update a person, you PUT to /person/1234 or /person/list

A person looks like this:

```
<person>
  <id>1234</id>
  <name>Name1</name>
  <age>50</age>
  <education>high school</education>
</person>
```

Question:
Can I use PUT to update a person by sending

```
<person>
  <age>55</age>
</person>
```

As I understand PUT, you cannot use it for incremental Updates. Shouldn't I use POST to do it?

Can we relax PUT's definition for this use-case to make the terminology simple. As then PUT will mean Update, POST will mean Create.

Assume that you cannot ask the client to send a complete resource representation for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be told repeatedly that you should not do a partial PUT.  The spec says you should not do it.  However, I've yet to hear a convincing argument as to what are negative impacts of doing it.

One of the longer threads on the subject is here http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/17500

Comment: Hi Darrel, maybe you can share some idea with this Restlet issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794041/using-xstream-extension-with-swagger-instead-of-jackson

Answer (score 1):

If your client supports it, I think [PATCH](http://semanticweb.com/http-patch-and-tracking-rdf-changes_b15382) is what you are looking for:

> **PATCH** to override a portion of a specified resource in a predictable and effectively transactional way (if the entire patch cannot be performed, the server should not do any part of it)

Comment: The client doesn't support it. I'm specifically looking to know if I can overload the meaning of PUT to do incremental updates for me. What're the issues I may run into if I do so.

Comment: What is the client? How exactly doesn't it allow PATCH?

Answer (score 0):

Although not very popular, there is a [PATCH verb in HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789). This is what it is intended, but not sure who implements it. POST is usually used to patch, but it is not REST-standard, as far as I know, but you can implement it if you get that convention in your environment.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know about PATCH and we may not be able to use it. However, the question is - can I use PUT to do incremental updates?

Comment: Well, of course you can do it, but it is not standard for several reasons. First, it is not standard *per se* (PUT is not specified for that, but for substituting the entire object); then, it may lead to inconsistent state (what if you put partially a non-existent object? information put may not be enouugh to build a functioning object), etc.